# Can't catch jQuery DOM Event that is inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dom-events

I have an `<iframe>` that contains a particular webpage. In that iframed webpage, the following Event trigger is setup via jQuery:

```
console.log($('.myElement').trigger('testEvent'));
```

This event is triggered every ~20 seconds.

Back on the parent page, when the page first loads, I setup an Event Handler for the event:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){

  console.log("Iframe loaded");

  $('iframe').contents().find('.myElement').on('testEvent', function(e) {
    console.log("Event Fired!", e);
  });

});
```

So once the iframe is loaded, the event handler is setup.

For some reason, the event handler never runs. The event is definitely being triggered because I see the result of the `console.log()` in the console. I don't see any errors or anything in the console.

Also I can manually trigger it and see that the handler is working:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.myElement').trigger('testEvent');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So the parent document and the iframe content document each have their own jQuery instance. Apparently it's not (easily?) possible for one instance of jQuery to listen for events triggered by the other instance of jQuery. My problem in the parent document was this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('.myElement').on('testEvent', function(e,data) {});
```

Here I'm trying to use the the parent jQuery to handle the event. This won't work. I have to use vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('#my_iframe').contentWindow.$('.myElement').on('testEvent'), function(e,data) {});
```

So here I'm using vanilla JavaScript to get to the iframe contents and then the jQuery from that point on is the iframe's jQuery instance, which is the same instance of jQuery that the trigger happens on.

This worked perfectly!